# Why does this program cause so many cache misses?

Tags: c, performance, caching

I'm stuck with a question about cache performance in the below practice exam. Could you please give me some hints on how to solve it? Here is my draft answer:

1. The arrays a, b span the entire 32 pages of the cache.
2. The loop runs twice so the first loop will warm up the cache. 2048 is the number of cold misses caused by the a[i], b[i] assignments in the first loop.
3. In OS1, the cache is virtually indexed because the translations cause more cache misses in trials 1 and 3 (although I cannot explain the dramatic drop and increase in trials 2 and 3).
4. In OS2, the cache is physically indexed.
5. In part (c) the candidate page placement strategies that reduce cache misses are page coloring and bin hopping, but I dont know how to decide which one is used.

I appreciate any hints. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Forget my first comment. I didn't see the virtual vs. physical indexing stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) The cache is physically indexed. The OS is allocating "random" physical pages causing a large deviation in test results. If the cache was virtually indexed there would be no large deviation in test results (as there would be no large deviation in virtual addresses used).

b) The most likely explanation is that the second OS is not allocating "random" physical pages (e.g. some sort of page colouring scheme - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coloring ).

c) I'd use a search engine to discover more information about the strategy used by OS 2.

Note 1: I have no idea what the answer for the last question should be (seems like a silly question to me).

Note 2: The cache is hardware and won't magically redesign its own silicon (e.g. from virtually indexed to physically indexed) when a different OS is installed.